# how beego get input type="datetime-local" with ParseForm?

Tags: html, go, beego

I define a struct in beego and add form tag to realtive fields, and the input type="datetime-local" in html

struct code:

```
type TaskModifyForm struct {
    ID           int        `form:"id"`
    Name         string     `form:"name"`
    Status       string     `form:"status"`
    Content      string     `form:"content"`
    UserCode     string     `form:"user_code"`
    StartTime    *time.Time `form:"start_time"`
    CompleteTime *time.Time `form:"complete_time"`
    DeadlineTime *time.Time `form:"deadline_time"`
}
```

html code：

```
<div class="d-inline-flex row m-2">
      <label class="form-label col-4" for="completetime">end time</label>
           <div class="col-8">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="datetime-local"                                 id="deadlinetime" name="deadline_time" value="{{ datetimeFormat2 .task.DeadlineTime }}"/>
           </div>
</div>
```

beego controller code:

```
func (c *TaskController) Modify() {
    form := new(forms.TaskModifyForm)
    task := new(models.Task)
    errs := errors.New()

    if c.Ctx.Input.IsPost() {
        //post请求
        err := c.ParseForm(form)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

I have tried many times, but it still doesn't work, any advice will be great appreciated！